# Error Unhandled exception:'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 6002: character maps to <undefined> Check the log for more details

Tags: mysql-workbench, csv-import

I'm trying to upload a .csv to MySQL but I get this error:

> Unhandled exception:'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 6002: character maps to <undefined> Check the log for more details.

The .csv is merged with already pre-existing but empty tables.

I have tried to upload as many as cvs UTF-8 and delimited by commas but the error persists.

[Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sua8P.jpg)

Comment: This is an application error, you need to ask mysql support for help.

Comment: Pardon me if I am stating the obvious, but did you check the log (as suggested in the error message)? It seems like there is a problem in the CSV file. Can you [edit] your question and post that file? Or at least the part containing the byte that cannot be decoded?